# SonarSource for Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sonarqube

I'm trying to use SonarSource for my Android project development for which I followed the steps provided [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse) to installing Sonar Eclipse plug-in, when I try to associate my android project with Sonar it asks for groupId and artifactId, I have no idea about these two and after some surfing it seems that groupId is nothing but my project package(but not sure), and for artifactId I gave my project name, after selecting the desired sonar server and clicking on finish button I'm getting unknowm error occurred at top left corner of Associate with Sonar window.
So can someone guide me how to use SonarSource for Android project or share a link for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: When you select your server, can you select your sonar project from there? Or have you never before executed an analysis?

Comment: I have never executed an analysis before.

Comment: The "gotcha" here is that Sonar is ideally designed to be run from your automated build server, at least once a day to refresh your dashboard. The Eclipse plug-in, on the other hand, is designed as a supplimentary tool, to run your analysis locally on your uncommitted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If people are interested by this thread. We recently pushed a [GitHub project](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android) that combines many testing technologies together for the Android platform and emphasizes on Sonar integration.

We combined (and the list is not exhaustive) :

- robolectric
- standard junit tests
- robotium
- ui automator
- code coverage using emma, cobertura and jacoco offline
- mocking frameworks like easy mock and mockito
- etc.

And, for most of them, we propose a solution to display this all in Sonar.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to have analysed your project successfully on a Sonar server prior to being able to associate it in Eclipse with Sonar Eclipse.

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who looking for the same, here is what I do to make it work.
I simply followed this [link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task) and written ant build for my project and made the configuration in the file and deployed my code in Sonar and everything works fine. But for your information its not Android specific its just POJO specific.